# Find the union of two sets of 10 digit numbers

Tags: c

I'm trying to find the union of two sets of 10 digit numbers, I'm passing along three int arrays: first, second, and comp (this will hold the union set).

So far, I've added first and second into one array. I was thinking about finding the matching indices in comp[] then filter through deleting them. I figure there's a much easier way. Can anyone give me a hint?

Basically I'm taking

```
first[] = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
second[] = [1,2,3,4,11,12,13,14,15,16];
```

and I want to return

```
comp[] = [5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16];
```

The numbers won't necessarily be in order.

```
int compound(int first[],int second[],int comp[]){
int i=0;
int indicies[20];
for(int j = 0; j<SIZE; j++){
    comp[i]=first[j];
    i++;
}

for(int k = 0; k<SIZE; k++){
    comp[i]=second[k];
    i++;
}
int z=0;
for(int l = 0; l<SIZE*2; l++){
    for(int m = 0; m<SIZE*2; m++){
        if(comp[l]==comp[m]){
            indicies[z]=m;
            z++;
        }}}


return 0;
}
```

Comment: Isn't that the union minus the intersection?

Comment: Are you familiar with the concept of a *[hash table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table)*?

Comment: How do you want to communicated how big the result is?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A first good step is (nearly) always sorting.

Sort both input-sets (unless you know they are already sorted).

Then iterate over both at once (two indices) and only add those elements to the output which fulfill your criteria (seems to be union minus intersection, thus only in one).

Bonus: The output-set will be sorted.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you start by writing a `contains(int[], int)` method like

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool contains(int arr[], int val) {
  int offset;
  for (offset = 0; arr[offset] != '\0'; offset++) {
    if (arr[offset] == val) return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Then your `compound` method could be implemented using it with something like

```
int compound(int first[],int second[],int comp[]){
  int i=0;
  int j;
  for(j = 0; first[j] != '\0'; j++){
    int val = first[j];
    if (contains(second, val) && !contains(comp, val))
      comp[i++] = val;
  }
  return i;
}
```

Finally, you can test it like

```
int main(int argc, char *args[]) {
  int a[] = {1,2,3,'\0'};
  int b[] = {2,3,4,'\0'};
  int c[3];
  int count = compound(a,b,c);
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    printf("%i\n", c[i]);
  }
}
```

Output is

```
2
3
```

Comment: Your `c` array is too small to hold the result `1,2,3,4`.

Comment: isn't stdbool.h a C99's feature? if so, you could declare `offset` in first parameter of the `for`...

Comment: @Jack Not on my platform (without a flag to `gcc`).

Answer (score 1):

If the numeric range is small you could do this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX 20  // small numeric range

#define sz(a) (sizeof(a)/sizeof(*(a)))

int xunion(int *a, int sa, int *b, int sb, int *c) {
  int n[MAX] = {0};
  for (int i=0; i<sa; i++) n[a[i]] = 1;
  for (int i=0; i<sb; i++) n[b[i]] = 1;
  int j=0;
  for (int i=0; i<MAX; i++) if (n[i]) c[j++] = i;
  return j;
}

void prn(int *a, int s) {
  while (s-- > 0) printf("%d ", *a++);
  putchar('\n');
}

int main() {
  int a[] = {6, 3, 4, 7, 5};
  int b[] = {2, 4, 5, 7, 6, 3};
  int c[MAX];
  prn(a, sz(a));
  prn(b, sz(b));
  int n = xunion(a, sz(a), b, sz(b), c);
  prn(c, n);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I have no idea what's even happening here. haha

Comment: @BillTudor An array `n` is initialized to zeroes. Both input arrays are looped through, setting the corresponding element in `n` to 1. Then `n` is looped through and anywhere there's a 1, that index is one of the numbers in the original lists, so it's appended to the output array. `n` could be a byte array or even a bit array.